# declaration capture phase in compilation

Tags: c#, compilation, declaration, forward-declaration

languages like C and C++ rely on forward declarations to resolve cyclic dependencies in type or function declarations. In C#, this is not required anymore because the declaration capture phase is split in two phases; one capturing symbol names and a second one actually doing the symbol declaration construction.

Is there a standard name for the symbol name capture phase? i would assume that declaration capture would be left for the traditional phase that involves resolving all symbols in the declaration

Answer (score 2):

The C# compiler actually has a declaration phase where it builds the symbol table. The Roslyn C# compiler is not so clear, because not everything is done in large sweeping phases. Instead, each symbol is constructed individually, on demand. However, there is still a step where type and member declarations in syntax are converted into symbols. The binding phase comes after this logically, where references to type and member names are resolved using the declared symbol table.

Answer (score 1):

I think these two phases are called

1. parsing
2. binding

Parsing is syntactic. Binding is assigning meaning to identifiers and names.

C++ could do the same. It is just defined not to.

Comment: no i think the declaration capture phases happen once the AST is built, which is after the parsing phase is finished

Comment: Reading your comment I don't know what exactly you mean by declaration capture. AFAIK there is nothing between (1) and (2). What would such a phase do? The declarations have already been "captured" by the parser into an AST.

Comment: the binding phase you mentioned can be subdivided in sub-phases, symbol name resolution (not sure if that is the proper name), declaration capture, and finally binding proper which connects implementations to declarations, but this last phase continues during the link phase

Comment: I still don't know what "declaration capture" does and I could not find it on the web. Maybe I don't know enough about this topic. At least I can say that in a C# compiler no separate link phase is needed and I believe it does not exist. Once you know what AST-node the name "xyz" refers to you are done with binding (and linking). Nothing left to do.

Comment: i don't think is that simple; take two class declarations, one having a member of the other's type. The cyclical dependency can only be broken by first resolving the class names and **then** attaching declarations to those names

Comment: The declarations are there all the time. They might have the following data: { Name = "xyz", BoundTo = null }. Binding sets the BoundTo field, but the declaration has been there since parsing it. Cyclic dependencies are not a problem at all because binding does not introduce declarations. It just couples declarations and references together.

Comment: so what you are saying is that binding is the name for what i was calling 'symbol resolution', which happens before the class declarations are captured, with all their data members, methods, etc.

Comment: It does not. All class members can be "captured" without knowing what they refer to. For example the types of the fields just get captured as a string. The association to types happens later in the binding phase. You can parse all of C# into an AST without knowing a single type. In my answer, (1) goes from string to AST. (2) changes the AST only locally. It adds the info what the parsed-out names mean (e.g. "string" means "System.String[mscorlib]").

Answer (score 0):

With .Net 5 Microsoft will be introducing Roslyn, the compiler as a service. [This overview](http://innovation.tss-yonder.com/2012/01/11/compilers-as-a-service/) for Roslyn describes the compiler's three steps prior to code generation as being: lexical analysis, syntactic analysis and semantic analysis. The [Roslyn project's overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/hh500769) confirms these descriptions, but with less precise language.

Answer (score 0):

I found this blog post from Eric Lippert which gives the best explanation of what i was looking for:

> The C# language does not require that declarations occur before
>   usages, which has two impacts, again, on the user and on the compiler
>   writer. The impact on the user is that you don’t get to recompile just
>   the IL that changed when you change a file; the whole assembly is
>   recompiled. Fortunately the C# compiler is sufficiently fast that this
>   is seldom a huge issue. (Another way to look at this is that the
>   “granularity” of recompilation in C# is at the project level, not the
>   file level.)
>
> The impact on the compiler writer is that we have to have a “two pass”
>   compiler. In the first pass, we look for declarations and ignore
>   bodies. Once we have gleaned all the information from the declarations
>   that we would have got from the headers in C++, we take a second pass
>   over the code and generate the IL for the bodies.

...

> We then do a **"declaration" pass** where we make notes about the
>   location of every namespace and type declaration in the program. At
>   this point we're done looking at the source code for the first phase;
>   every subsequent pass is over the set of "symbols" deduced from the
>   declarations.
>
> We then do a pass where we verify that all the types declared have no
>   cycles in their base types. We need to do this first because in every
>   subsequent pass we need to be able to walk up type hierarchies without
>   having to deal with cycles.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/02/04/how-many-passes.aspx